# More professional ways to express "something else I have learned" as the title of a slide

Tags: academia

I am a PhD student and I was preparing a slide presentation for summarizing what I did and learned in the last year. My plan is first presenting research work progress and then showing what I have learned in some other aspects, e.g., how to balance life and science. What kind of title is suitable for this slide instead of "Something else I have learned"? I was thinking that "Something else I have learned" as the title would appear unprofessional.

Comment: Perhaps "Life balance and pastoral care". Try to present it as part of the package rather than a side-issue: education is about the whole journey.

Comment: “Other Insights”

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful suggestions. @WeatherVane@Xanne

Answer (score 0):

-anecdotal observation
or -incidental discovery ,
might be more appropriate in my experience with business and business students.
Your phrase is too casual for higher-level English in acedemia. It would be okay in an informal situation.

Comment: You should add some explanation of _why_ these suggestions are more appropriate.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes I also think my phrase is too casual.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this has already come and gone based on the date, but some other options that might work if still needed:

- Key takeaways (or "key takeaways over the last year") - This carries an implication that these are things you learned which you will take with you into the future.
- Learnings - This has become the default business jargon for "things I learned", and sounds a little more formal. (I personally think it's a *little* silly, but it's very common as a phrase.)
- Additional insights - Similar to one of the commenters above. If the point of the slide is specifically that these are things outside of the scope of the research, this might be useful ("Additional takeaways" or "Additional learnings" would also work). This boils down to "other things we saw."